# Conversion paths in looker studio

Tags: looker-studio, google-analytics-4

In Looker Studio, I am trying to show GA4 conversion paths and attribution for each
channel. There are currently no fields in Looker Studio for Conversion Paths? Anyone here can help me?

I came across this blog but it's saying to download data first in csv. I want to directly connect google analytics 4 to looker studio and see live data for conversion paths, can anybody help me?

https://coam.io/affiliate-marketing/how-to-see-assisted-conversions-in-ga4